# setContentView issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I am going through some tutorials in some Ebooks and one of the tutorials is to create the game Crazy Eights. I am at the beginning of this tutorial. So far I have created the project, added some details in the Mainifest, and I have also created a custom view named "MyView". The activity is CrazyEightsActivity.

Ok so my problem is this: I am adding some to the screenshots below about this also.

This one is the Main Activity:

[image]

This is the custom view (MyView):

[image]

In the tutorial, it calls for us to modify our main activity to set our custom view as the content view. I have copied everything so far (the code) and this little problem isn't allowing me to see the app (as it is created so far, not even close to being done) in the emulator. I need some help. It is underlinning the setContentView(MyView) line, I got a red square around it to help identify it. It gives me two quick fix options which both don't work. Whenever I run it after that, the emulator says that the app stopped running and had to be forced closed.

I am stuck, I hope that someone can help me. I am really trying to get this done ASAP so I can move on to the next tutorial and start learning this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
setContentView(new MyView(this));
```

Comment: Ok, so I was able to use this code above and solve the problem, but now it still is forcing close when I run it in the emulator. You think that has something to do with the emulator? I have no idea, I am still a beginner. lol

Comment: check logcat. You should be able to find the exception where it's failing. It will even tell you the file and line number.

Comment: This is all that it is telling me now about why it isn't booting up onto the emulator:

Comment: This is all that it is telling me now about why it isn't booting up onto the emulator: level: D, time: 04-03 17.57.02.665, PID: 214, TID: 214, application: com.dummies.androidgame.crazyeights, tag: dalvikvm, text: newInstance failed: no <init>(). I tried looking up what this meant but I am not getting anything. By the way, I do appreciate both of you guys helping me out on this.